# How do I fix the display of accented characters?

Tags: perl

I realize this is an older script, but I would appreciate
any help getting it to work properly. Years ago it worked
fine, but lately it's been acting funny.
Excuse the formatting please....

When I run it in the browser, the french accented characters
do not show properly. But in the text file that it generates,
they show just fine. What is happening here?

Perl version is v5.20.2
My database is MySQL, utf8_unicode_ci
The table is also utf8_unicode_ci

in browser: `HÃ©lÃ¨ne Rollan` and in file: `Hélène Rollan`

in browser: `` Coeur Ã l`Ã©coute `` and in file: `` Coeur à l`écoute ``

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use utf8;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw (:standard);
$q = new CGI;
use Encode;
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:utf8");

$user = "manager";

require "config.cgi";
&Create_DB_Connection;
$time = time(); 

sub Create_DB_Connection{
  use DBI;
  $DSN  = "DBI:mysql:$mysql_database:$mysql_hostname";
  $dbh  = DBI->connect($DSN, "$mysql_username", "$mysql_password", {mysql_enable_utf8 => 1}) || die return;
  if ($dbh) { $connected = "YES"; }
  return;
}

sub Do_SQL{
  eval{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
  };
$dbh->do(qq{SET NAMES 'utf8';});
    $sth->execute;
    return ($sth);
}

    &downline;

# Prepare and show tree of affiliates
sub downline {
($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $mon, $year, $dweek, $dyear, $daylight) = localtime(time());
$month = $mon;
$year = $year + 1900;
print $q->header;

print<<EOF;
    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Network Summary</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</HEAD>
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
A:visited {text-decoration: none;} 
A:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
A:link {text-decoration: none;} 
A:active {text-decoration: none;} 
.MEMBERS {font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; font-family: Verdana,verdana; color: FF0000;}
--> 
</style>
<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF" TEXT="000000" LINK="000080" VLINK="004080">
<center><font size=4 face=arial color=000000><b>Network Summary as of $month/$year</b><br>
<font face=verdana,arial size=1><a href=wmstats_en2.cgi>[return to main page]</a></font></center>
<p>
EOF

$featured_file = "/home/bruce/data/featured.txt";

$SQL="SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,SPONSOR_ID,CO_SPONSOR_ID,ID FROM main_members"; 
&Do_SQL;
  while ($row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref){
  $info{$row->{'ID'}} = [$row->{'FIRST_NAME'},$row->{'LAST_NAME'},$row->{'SPONSOR_ID'}];
  push @{ $kids{$row->{'CO_SPONSOR_ID'}} }, $row->{'ID'};
}
$kid = "$user";

if (!$kids{$kid}) { 
print<<EOF;
<center><b><font size=2 face=arial>There are currently no members in your downline</font></b><font size=4 face=arial color=000000><br><BR>
EOF
} else {
&crunch(1);
}

$o++;

sub crunch {

foreach $kid (@{ $kids{$kid} }) {
$newlevel++;
$payouts{$newlevel}++;
$levels{$newlevel}++; 
$total_downline++;
while ($b < $newlevel) { $report .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; $b++; } $b=0; 
$report .= "$newlevel: $kid - $info{$kid}[0] $info{$kid}[1] <br>";

# I added this to generate a text file
open (FILE, ">>$featured_file");
flock(FILE, 2);
print FILE "$newlevel: $kid - $info{$kid}[0] $info{$kid}[1] \n";
flock(FILE, 8);
close (FILE);

&crunch($newlevel);
$newlevel--;
delete($info{$kid});
} 
}
print<<EOF;
<center><table><tr><td valign=top nowrap>
<font face=verdana size=2>
$report
</td><td valign=top>
<table cellpadding=0><tr>
<td align=right nowrap><font face=verdana,arial size=2><b>Total Downline:<p>&nbsp;</td><td><font face=verdana,arial size=2><b>&nbsp; $total_downline<p>&nbsp;</td></tr>
EOF

while (!$found_some) { $i++;
if ($levels{$i}) {
print<<EOF;
<tr><td align=right><font face=verdana,arial size=2><b>Level $i:</td><td><font face=verdana,arial size=2><b>&nbsp; $levels{$i}</td></tr>
EOF
} else { $found_some = 1; }
}

print<<EOF;
</td></tr></table>
<p><font face=verdana size=2><b>
</TD></TR></TABLE></TD></TR></TABLE>
EOF
}
```

Comment: Could you please reduce that to the 10 essential lines?

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `SELECT HEX(the_field_in_question)` to make sure the data is correct in the database?

Answer (score 1):

After removing the irrelevant bits and fixing the problem, you get the following. (If you had removed the irrelevant bits from the Question itself, it would be easier to see the differences.)

```
# Specifies the file is encoded using UTF-8.
# This doesn't matter for this program.
use utf8;

# Set the encoding for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR.
# Set the default encoding for file handles.
use open ':std', ':encoding(utf-8)';

use CGI      qw( );
use DBI      qw( );
use FindBin  qw( $RealBin );
use Template qw( );

my $cgi = CGI->new();

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
   "dbi:mysql:...",
   "...",
   "...",
   {
       RaiseError => 1,
       PrintError => 0,
       PrintWarn  => 1,

       # Decodes strings from the database.
       # Specifying this now performs SET NAMES 'UTF8'
       mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
   },
);

my $val = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT ...');

{
   open(my $fh, '>', '...')
      or die(...);

   print($fh $val);
}

{
    print $cgi->header('text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    my %vars = (
       val => $val,
    );

    my $tt = Template->new({
       ENCODING     => "UTF-8",
       INCLUDE_PATH => "$RealBin/tmpl",
    });

    $tt->process('test.tmpl', \%vars)
       or die($tt->error());
}
```

`tmpl/test.tmpl`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
[% val | html %]
</body>
</html>
```

That is, of course, assuming the data in the database is correct. My request to have this verified has gone unanswered.

Comment: This is fine except there is no calculation of the affiliate tree as in my code under the crunch routine.

Comment: So what? That had nothing to do with your problem. Again, please fix your question so it's a *minimal* demonstration of your problem